# Splitting text_field by commas for nested, polymorphic tagging form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

I have a tag model that is polymorphic, and which is also nested under microposts (so that the user can submit both the micropost and tag in the same "form for").

So far, the form submits successfully, and the micropost saves and the tag saves to my tags table.

However, what I want to do is split whatever is submitted in the tags text_field (where it says "jobs, engineering" below) into separate tags and split it with a split(", ")

Here is the POST console output when i click the submit button:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T/GieqxRM7Kxl2jmC7hr3KPixM/jVG4pdMi/ceb1Vq0=", "micropost"=>{"content"=>"This is a post", "tags_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"jobs, engineering"}}}, "commit"=>"Post"}
```

Would the best way to do this to write it into the "Create" method in the micropost controller (and if so, can someone point me in the right direction)?

(Note: I saw that there was a related question but I think they were using HAML so I didn't follow it)

Also, I'm not sure why the `0` shows up as a hash key. I think it might be because I put this below in my `form_for(@micropost)`, but if I don't put it there my tag text_field disappears.

```
% @micropost.tags.build %
```

Answer (score 0):

First the hash tags_attributes starts with 0 as a hash key because it is a nested resource. If you have multiple nested models submitted at the same time you would see

```
"tags_attributes" => { "0" => {...}, "1" => {...} }
```

This keeps the data for each nested record together and will iterate over the hash to create as many records as submitted.

Second, I would solve the problem using a before_filter which would take the submitted params hash and return a new hash in the format that you are looking for. Something like the following:

```
before_filter :new_params, only: [:create, :update]


private

def new_params
  params["tags_attributes"].each do |key, value| 
    value["name"] = value["name"].split(", ") }
  end
  params
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that info on the "0" hash key! Also, i will try the before_filter method, appreciate it!